# NETWORK_PROVIDER Location Accuracy Issue in Android

Tags: android, location

I have implemented Location Based Services using **Network Location Provider** it doesn't providing me the accurate location. My question is

1. How Network Location Provider Works? And why its not provide the accurate location.
2. What is the alternative way to get the Accurate location (I don't have the services of GPS indoor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Network location provider is based on data from cellular network base stations. This location data is always innacurate cause' it is some kind of estimation. It depends on number of base stations around you and quality of signal. Also Network provider can get a location based on a WiFi stations SSIDs around you. This is usual more accurate than cellular network base stations method. You can't select what kind of network to use, it is up to Android OS. Network provider using some kind of [triangulation algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation). Also see [Mobile phone tracking : network-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking)
2. No indoor alternative.