# How to detect device is stationary without using GPS, Accelerometer

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location

Is their any way for deciding the device is stationary without using GPS and accelerometer.

I can use network updates from location manager.

I tried using

```
 mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 10, mLocListener);
```

Considering i will receive location updates only if device moves atleast 10 meters. So absence of network updates can say device position stationary.

But this didnt seem to work properly. I even moved 200 meters or more i got no updates.
Is their any way to make it work.
Or any other way.

Thank You

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I really wonder why default method of android os dont provide us update after covering min distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network_provider depends hugely on how many cell towers are in your area. Using that method, accuracy can be as large as a few miles. This link mentions some alternatives like triangulating using what WiFi SSIDs are in range. Hope this helps!

[NETWORK_PROVIDER Location Accuracy Issue in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535561/network-provider-location-accuracy-issue-in-android)

Comment: thank you for the reply. but this didn't seem to work. We know network updates are inaccurate. can we use two inaccurate result to tell device is stationary or moving.

Comment: Good point. I should have used the word precision, not accuracy. As far as I know, your network_provider position is calculated based on what towers are in range. Unless you move far enough that one tower moves out of range or another moves in range then you won't see a change in the calculated position. They may have some crude range component in the calculation but taking into account 3 dimensions of space and one clock correction (4th dimension) you would need at least four towers in view to do this.

Comment: They may also use the power of the received signal to assume a range, but this would depend hugely on your physical surroundings ie. in a city with tall buildings vs. an open field.

Comment: Just found out that it does use signal strength to assume range. Check out this wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking

Comment: @GPSmasster thank you for all the reply. i will go through with this link and will get back to you again.